# Why doesn't Skype theme match my Desktop Environment theme?

Tags: themes, skype

I've got Ubuntu 12.10 installed on my PC. After enabling the partner sources, installing Skype, rebooting my PC and starting Skype, I notice visual differences between my Desktop theme and Skype theme. My theme is the default Ambience Theme. Anyone got any clues?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## In 14.04 (Trusty Tahr) 15.10 (Wily Werewolf) 16.04 (Xenial Xerus)

On Trusty (and above), you don't need the entire i386 lib stack, just install:

`sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-murrine:i386 gtk2-engines-pixbuf:i386`

Comment: Great, thanks. This only adds 338kB (versus a whopping 144MB for ia32-libs-gtk).

Comment: This fixes the issue on Ubuntu 15.04, the old answer was out of date.

Comment: I could barely notice a difference..

Comment: I can confirm that this solution works also in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 11):

I have found a solution for this problem: The odd look is caused because of the fact that skype is a 32 bit application, so if you are on a 64-bit system (which you are, because you suffer from this problem) you need to install additional 32-bit libaries to solve this issue. Just run:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-gtk
```

restart skype an everything will look integrated! (This libary will use 144 MB of additional space!)

Hope that works for you too!

Comment: This worked :D I never saw the answer before! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Skype 4.1 on Ubuntu 12.04. To change theme, go to "Options" and then on the "General" tab you'll see "Choose style."[image: skype options screenshot]

Comment: It doesn't help though..

Comment: did you try the different settings (not Desktop but GTK+) to find the one you want?

Comment: and click apply?

Comment: same thing, doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I followed the advice on https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1226775 and made my Skype look good.

> **Application Appearance > Colors** to oxygen in KDE settings